# How to recreate recent-apps activity when app is launched from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

My app and activity is in my list of **recent apps** when I receive a notification. When I click on the notification, I want the intent of the notification to be honored. In my case I want to restart the activity (brute force) and pass in the new intent: so, finish then re-create. I am reading about such tags as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` but I don't understand them enough to know how to force a "finish then re-create` of my activity. And, oh, the activity in question is MainActivity.

The snippet inside GcmListenerService uses

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

for sending the notification intent

**Alternatively**

If I go with `onNewIntent` things get complicated because there maybe DialogFragments being displayed, etc. And I would have to clear everything. That is why finish then re-create seem like the simplest solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP should produce the desired behavior.  The [documentation for Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) says this in the section for Using Intent Flags:

> If the launch mode of the designated activity is "standard", it too is
>   removed from the stack and a new instance is launched in its place to
>   handle the incoming intent. That's because a new instance is always
>   created for a new intent when the launch mode is "standard".

The [documentation for FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) describes the same behavior in more detail.